# cannot reach options on grub menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm newbie ubuntu user. I installed ubuntu about 2 weeks ago with dual boot w10. 
Today I came across with this thing. My grub menu which had 4 options(ubuntu,advanced ubuntu,windows and one other), shows full purple screen. and pc directly opens with ubuntu as normal. firstly screen shows acer logo, secondly the purple screen which would have to be grub menu, after that acer logo again, after that ubuntu logo with 5 dots and opens ubuntu. what can I do to reach my normal grub menu with 4 options.Thanks.[purple screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO3lu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that after an upgrade (or something like this) timeout value has been changed to 0 and your boot process goes straight up to Ubuntu menu entry. You can find many solutions to the issue. For example this one https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/